# jQuery Form Validation simple example not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation

I am trying to learn how to validate forms using jQuery. I found a example online and tried to follow it, but other than the HTML5 Email validation, no other validation is working. I have tried to change the execution of the jQuery function from Document.ready to form.on('submit'.... but that didn't work either. My js file is available on the path that I have specified which I checked by doing ctrl+U and clicking on the path, same for my jQuery src and validation src. Can someone please tell me why this is not working and any hints as how to fix this.

This is a JSFiddle link to my code:
[jQuery Code](https://jsfiddle.net/Ghos3t/s43wmmgg/1/)

Also my code just in case:

HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="form-validation.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
  <h2>Registration</h2>
  <form action="C:\Users\ito1910\Desktop\jquery practice\jquery_test.html" name="registration" id="registration">

    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="John"/>

    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Doe"/>

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="john@doe.com"/>

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;"/>


    <button type="submit">Register</button>

  </form>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
 // Wait for the DOM to be ready
$(function() {
  // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
  // It has the name attribute "registration"
  $("#registration").validate({
    // Specify validation rules
    rules: {
      // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
      // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
      // on the right side
      firstname: "required",
      lastname: "required",
      email: {
        required: true,
        // Specify that email should be validated
        // by the built-in "email" rule
        email: true
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      }
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
      lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
      password: {
        required: "Please provide a password",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
      },
      email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");

/* Styles */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

form {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #2c3e50;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
form label,
form input,
form button {
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
form input {
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0 6px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form button {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #e67e22;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form .error {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: 1) `libraries/jquery-validation-1.16.0.zip` path with zip file is not correct , make sure to add a `.js` file . 2) Make sure that you have the paths `js/form-validation.js` , `libraries/jquery-3.2.1.js` and `libraries/jquery-validation-1.16.0.js` accessible and spelled correctly .

Comment: @Ashraf I have changed the Validation src to Google CDN as I could not understand the ZIP folder I have. I have also moved the CSS and JS files into the same directory as the HTML file for simplicity. Still doesn't work though.

Comment: @user258365 please define "not working" - do you get a console error, or some unexpected behaviour, or what? "Not working" is not an adequate description of your problem. Please also consider updating your fiddle with the latest version of your code. P.S. At the moment, in your example, you are referencing jQuery twice (once from the CDN, once from a local file) - if both files actually exist, this will cause problems.

Comment: Other observations: 1) `$("form[name='registration']").validate({` could be simplified to `$("#registration").validate({` since your form has an ID. jQuery will work faster to find this, as well, rather than an attribute search. 2) The "action" of your form is invalid. You can't reference local files for a postback like this. You need a webserver running on your machine (IIS Express is free and would be fine for this kind of testing) and a "http://..." URL, although it looks like you don't have any server code to post back to anyway, so nothing will happen even if you do a valid postback.

Comment: @ADyson I corrected the error of referencing the jQuery twice and made the changes in the js file you suggested. By not working I mean the validation of user input is not happening. I don't get the messages that I have written in the jQuery code like- "Your password must be at least 5 characters long", "Please enter your firstname" etc. It just directly goes to the next page.

Comment: in that case please check your browser console for error first - are there any? (Press F12 to get the developer tools, including console, to show, if you didn't know already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing my validation to fail. The CDN URL I was using, turns out my companys firewall was blocking it. So I just downloaded the zip file from the jqueryvalidation.org and manually copied the jquery.validate.js file from inside the dist folder and used that. now it's working, thank you @Ashraf and @ADyson for your help.